# Removing profile folder access credentials in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, security, login

I was logged in to the public account on a Windows 10 computer that I manage, and I needed to copy some files from the admin account. As the public user I browsed admin's files using File Explorer (I had to provide the admin password obviously), but now public user can access the admin's files even after a reboot. Is there a fix for this?

Comment: "Is there a fix for this?" - It sounds like you took ownership of the folder or added the guest account to the ACL of the folder.  The simplest solution would be to reset the ACL on the folder in question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually modified the NTFS permissions on the admin account's user folder.

1. Navigate to the `%SystemDrive%\Users` hierarchy while logged in with admin privileges.
2. Right-click the admin user's profile folder and select `Properties`.
3. Select the `Security` tab.
4. Find the public account within the `Group or user names` field, then click the `Edit` button.

   [image: Edit]
5. In the subsequent window select that same public account name and click `Remove`.

   [image: Remove]
6. Once the permission updates have finished propagating, click `OK` in both open windows to exit.

After that, your "public account" shouldn't have access to the admin user's folder.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Sorry about the title, I wasn't really sure what was going on.

Comment: No problem, it was a simple misunderstanding in terminology.  I'm glad that you were able to return things back to normal.